# Websphere application server dissable session persistence across nodes

Tags: soap, websphere, port

WAS app server 9.
Two nodes port 9081/9082 running same application but different versions.

Log into app 1. Fine

Change url/port to app 2 it auto logs in, reusing app 1 credentials.

I get an error in the logs at that point that app2 has tried to use app1's soap port.

Everything works fine and can switch ports/ applications without further errors.

Using different session ids for WAS nodes and also different between the apps.

I can only think is some session persistence based on the same domain name.

Please any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: There are a few things not clear in your post: are you using 2 separate nodes (different hosts) or 2 servers (JVMs) on the same host (node)? Are they part of the same cell managed by dmgr or standalone? Is the app using same root-context on both servers? Session cookie is different based on host/context params NOT the port. So if your apps versions URLs differ only in port, then they might share same session depending on the settings. There is no persistence by default configured, only session affinity.

Comment: One host server, two nodes . I have been looking at the session settings in WAS, seeing if I can some way do this. I think the only way is have a different context root per application, rather then just a node variation will be the only way I can do this. Currently it is http:\\server1:9080\app and http:\\server1:9081\app.

Comment: You have 2 other options: 1) change the session cookie name for each application; 2) create 2 virtual hosts, like http://app1.server1 and http://app2.server1